Tracking state when changing routes - Page Loading
Dependencies:

Nextjs v15
Reactjs v18
Prime React v10.8.5(UI Lib)
Typescrpt
Prime Flex

Problem:
I made a basic hamburger menu with prime react components, I want to add a loading animation when a route is clicked, then when a new route is loaded the animation should stop.
Code:
Below you will see two files that have this set up however the loading animation is being triggered when opening the menu instead of when clicking a route. I've tried a few different methods and cant seem to figure out a working one

<MenuModel/> Hamburger Parent Component
'use client';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
import { Sidebar } from 'primereact/sidebar';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { MobileMenu } from './MobileMenu';
import LoadMask from '../LoadMask';
import SVGBackground from '../backgrounds/svg/SVGBackground';

export const MenuModel = () => {

    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const onClose = () => {
        if (!isLoading && visible) {
            setVisible(false);
            setIsLoading(true);
        }
    };
   
    return (
        <>
            <Button
                icon={'fa-solid fa-bars'}
                onClick={() => setVisible(true)}
                style={{
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '2rem',
                    right: '2rem',
                    padding: '5px',
                    zIndex: 999,
                }}
                pt={{
                    root: {
                        style: {
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                        },
                    },
                }}
            />
            <Sidebar
                visible={visible}
                onHide={() => setVisible(false)}
                position='right'
                className='flex justify-content-center align-content-center sideMenu bg-black-alpha-90'
                closeIcon={
                    <i
                        className='fa-solid fa-xmark fa-lg cursor-pointer hover:shadow-4'
                        style={{ color: 'white', zIndex: 999 }}
                    />
                }
            >
                <MobileMenu onClose={onClose} />
                <LoadMask loading={isLoading} /> //this is a typical load mask and shows when true
            </Sidebar>
        </>
    );
};


<MobileMenu/> - shows when hamburger menu is open
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { Ripple } from 'primereact/ripple';
import XYButton from '../Inputs/XYButton'; // same as prime react <Button/>

const BUTTON_SYLE = 'p-2 font-bold w-11';
interface MenuItem {
    label: string;
    route: string;
}
interface MobileMenuProps {
    onClose: () => void;
}
export const MobileMenu = ({ onClose }: MobileMenuProps) => {
    const currentRoute = window.location.pathname;
    const router = useRouter();
    const handleNavigateClick = (to: string) => {
        router.push(`/${to}`);
        onClose();
    };

    const MENU: MenuItem[] = [
        { label: 'Home', route: '' },
        {
            label: 'Project Gallery',
            route: 'projectGallery',
        },
        {
            label: 'Our Team',
            route: 'team',
        },
        {
            label: 'About XYS',
            route: 'about',
        },
        {
            label: 'Client Portal',
            route: 'login',
        },

        {
            label: 'Privacy & Terms',
            route: 'privacy',
        },
    ];
    function filterMenuByLabel(
        menu: MenuItem[],
        labelToRemove: string
    ): MenuItem[] {
        return menu.filter(
            (item) => item.route !== labelToRemove.replace('/', '')
        );
    }
    const MENU_WITHOUT_CURRENT_ROUTE: MenuItem[] = filterMenuByLabel(
        MENU,
        currentRoute
    );
    return (
        <div className='flex flex-column p-1 mobileMenu gap-4 justify-content-center align-content-center'>
            {MENU_WITHOUT_CURRENT_ROUTE.map((page) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        key={page.route}
                        className='flex justify-content-center align-items-center'
                    >
                        <XYButton
                            key={page.route + '-x'}
                            className={BUTTON_SYLE}
                            label={page.label}
                            onClick={() => handleNavigateClick(page.route)}
                            xyType='transparentWhite'
                        >
                            <Ripple
                                pt={{
                                    root: {
                                        style: {
                                            background: 'rgba(0, 14, 0, .4)',
                                        },
                                    },
                                }}
                            />
                        </XYButton>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};


